# Hangfire - Creating a new DirectorySearcher object with a DirectoryEntry as an argument throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, hangfire

I am trying to create a `DirectorySearcher` object using an existing `DirectoryEntry` object, but when I do it throws a `System.NullReferenceException` on that line. The following works in a standalone .NET 6.0 Console application, but not in a .Net 6.0 Console application that is doing work as a worker for a Hangfire Server. Here is the class and method that I get the exception with:

```
public class LocalADConnector : IADConnector
{
    public void GetUserADInfo(string username, string saGUID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username), $"Argument {nameof(username)} of type {username.GetType()} may not be null or empty."); }    
        using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(_adServer, _adUser, _adPass))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)) //Exception is thrown here.
            {
                dirSearcher.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName={username}))";

                using (DirectoryEntry adUser = dirSearcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    if (adUser == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException($"User with the username {username} does not exist!");
                    }

                    foreach (string property in adUser.Properties.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{property}: {adUser.Properties[property].Value}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method that will get enqueued by Hangfire through the web project, and then executed by a Windows service:

```
public void UpdateUser(string employeeID, IHRConnector hrConnector, IADConnector adConnector, string saGUID)
{
    try
    {
        adConnector.GetUserADInfo(employeeID, saGUID);

        //There is other stuff here, but it's not relevant.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And here is the serialization settings for Hangfire:

```
builder.Services.AddHangfire(config =>
    config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
    .UseSerializerSettings(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto
    })
    .UseSqlServerStorage($"{builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireDB")}uid={Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LGN_HF_USR", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)};pwd={Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LGN_HF_PWD", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)}", new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorageOptions { SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) })
);
```

I have tried creating the objects and then applying the properties after, but the exception occurs at the

```
dirSearcher.SearchRoot = dirEntry;
```

line. Creating a `DirectorySearcher` object in the immediate window using `dirEntry` works just fine.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

The `NullReferenceException` occurred on a different logging line when I tried creating a default `DirectorySearcher`, so I think the actual object that this method is in is getting cleaned up/set to null for some reason.

UPDATE 2:

I'm convinced this issue is coming from having an interface as one of the arguments for the method enqueued by Hangfire. I have updated the code above to show more of the problem.

Comment: Some things to check: Confirm `dirEntry` is actually null when the error happens. Possible permission issue? Try running the worker under a different account context. Try this overload: `new DirectoryEntry(_adServer, _adUser, _adPass, AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer)`. Try a different authentication type besides `ReadonlyServer`.

Comment: Assigning to `SearchRoot` should not cause a Null Reference Exception. Are you sure that is where the error is occurring?

Comment: @TawabWakil `dirEntry` is not null, and I can expand the children and see items underneath, so I don't think permissions are the issue. I also tried both `ReadOnlyServer` and `Secure` and experienced the same result.

@NetMage When I step through, assigning at `SearchRoot` kicks me to the end of the method with the same exception, so I am confident it's happening there.

Comment: If `dirEntry` is not null, what else could be throwing the null reference error? Is the error happening only in the deployed app (i.e., not in the debugger)? If so, you may need to add logging to figure out what is null.

Comment: @TawabWakil It's happening in the debugger. I'm not sure what would be null; possibly a value that doesn't get set properly in the `DirectoryEntry`, but I'm not sure how `DirectorySearcher` uses a `DirectoryEntry`, and what property that would be.

Comment: Good question. As far as I know, the only thing that could cause a null reference exception in that `using` line would be if `dirEntry` were null, unless you've hit on a bug in .NET where it doesn't play well with Hangfire. You might try doing a clean/rebuild and restarting the machine, just as a sanity check. You could also consider hosting the app in Task Scheduler or another alternative to Hangfire since your code works as a standalone console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but the issue was that I was debugging in Release and not Debug, so it wasn't giving me the correct line that the `System.NullReferenceException` was happening on. Specifically, the exception was from trying to get the value of an AD property that didn't exist. Thanks for everyone's help, and [Bing Chat](https://bing.com/chat) for pointing me in the right direction.